# Children's book on travelling through portal rings to other realms done by young girl held at an institution

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This children's novel was from around the 1970s or early 1980s.

Chris changes shape to fit into each realm. The guards follow her each time. She later finds she is a clone of the scientist Christine, who went through a double ring.

Comment: Do you have anymore details you could [edit] in? Any plot elements? Memorable scenes? What the cover looked like? etc.

Comment: Spaceling by Doris Pischeria?  The ability to see other-dimensional rings that float in Earth's atmosphere was a late mutation of a few space-age humans. Daryl was under the care of the institution for muters, and she had discovered that if you jumped through the right ring at the right time it would land you in another dimensional world and another shape.

Comment: @sueeIleker: I agree with Doris Piserchia's *Spaceling* - I also immediately thought about it. You should expand it into a full answer.

Comment: Can you expand it for me? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: If _Spaceling_ is correct, this can be closed as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33634/looking-for-a-pre-1975-young-adult-sci-fi-colored-circle-dimension-crossing